# Using regexp in haskell function guards

Tags: regex, haskell, idioms

I would like to write a Haskell function that's behavior is dependent upon regex pattern matching one of the arguments. In a language like C/Python/Perl, I would definitely just use a large if/else construct, but I don't really have that option.  What is the most idiomatic Haskell way to handle this?

I've considered guards, but they don't work: `No instance for (Data.String.IsString source0)`:

```
function arg
  | arg =~ "pattern1" = dothis arg
  | arg =~ "pattern2" = dothat arg
  | otherwise = failwith arg
```

The pattern matching used in case constructs would be perfect, if it handled Regex.

```
function arg = case arg of
  (pattern1 match) -> dothis match
  (pattern2 match) -> dothat match
  _ -> failwith arg
```

Comment: in the version using gaurds, you probably need explicit type annotations, something like `function :: String -> ReturnType`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first example *does* work for me:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix

function :: String -> String
function arg
  | arg =~ "pattern1" = "1"
  | arg =~ "pattern2" = "2"
  | otherwise = "3"
```

I think your `IsString` error is due to the overloaded string literals extension. Try to disable that, or alternatively try to use explicit `String` strings:

```
function :: String -> String
function arg
  | arg =~ ("pattern1"::String) = "1"
  | arg =~ ("pattern2"::String) = "2"
  | otherwise = "3"
```

Too noisy? You can push the cruft to the last lines.

```
function2 :: String -> String
function2 arg
  | arg =~ s"pattern1" = "1"
  | arg =~ s"pattern2" = "2"
  | otherwise = "3"
  where s :: String -> String
        s = id
```

Need subgroup matching?

```
function3 :: String -> String
function3 arg
  | [_,x]:_ <- arg =~ s"pat(t*)ern1" = "matched group: " ++ x
  -- ...
```

On `function3 "patttern1"`, variable `x` will be bound to `"tt"`. On `function3 "xyz"`, the test will fail and the next branch will be tried.

Comment: `PatternGuards` are standard, no pragma needed. `ViewPatterns` might be even closer to what OP asks for, or the even more newfangled `PatternSynonyms`.

Comment: @matejcik Because the `=~` has many overloads, including one returning list-of-lists, which I exploit here. I don't recall all the details, since I answered this 3 years ago, but the library docs should probably contain them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, which was helpful! (Though for the `function3` form I am always seeing that the first guard matches, even if the match is empty.)